# Spring boot tomcat initialized successfully but not listening port found

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I try to use `netstat -aon | findstr 8088` to find the port but not found.

application.properties :

```
server.host=localhost
server.port=8088
server.context-path=/
server.tomcat.accesslog.enabled=true
server.tomcat.accesslog.pattern=%t %a "%r" %s (%D ms)
```

console output without any error logs:(JDK8 + IDEA + WIN7）

```
2018-02-11 17:10:26.374 [main] INFO  o.s.b.c.e.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer - Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8088 (http)
2018-02-11 17:10:26.383 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService - Starting service [Tomcat]
2018-02-11 17:10:26.384 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine - Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.16
2018-02-11 17:10:26.510 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.a.c.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/] - Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2018-02-11 17:10:26.510 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Published root WebApplicationContext as ServletContext attribute with name [org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext.ROOT]
2018-02-11 17:10:26.510 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1636 ms
```

Finally ,I changed to a already used port then start app, it still prints success log, LOL, Not any error logs can found, how can i find the issue?

Comment: And what is exactly the problem? You specify port 8088 in application.properties and tomcat starts on port 8088. If you don't see results in netstat, you probably have issues in the netstat command itself (wrong syntax/logical error/running with wrong privilege/ etc.)

Comment: Because i try to access localhost:8088 then got a connect refused ,so i check the port use `netstat`, it told me not such port listening

Comment: do you have a firewall running?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I found the reason by myself, One @Bean block the spring init main thread, tomcat bind not yet. It's very ridiculous. This bean was netty, i must change another way init.

Comment: Did you have to remove the bean or how did you get around this?